# Run discord.py client on current event loop

Tags: discord.py, python-asyncio

i am working on a discord.py bot and I want to run the discord.py client from the current event asyncio loop

```
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

async def start():
    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')
    
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print("Ready")
    
    client.run('token')
    
asyncio.run(start())
```

Is it possible to do such?

Comment: It looks possible according to [the documentation for `run`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.run).

Comment: Solved - client.run uses the current asyncio loop

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've made a start function and called `client.run('token')` in it. This is close, however, you must look at [how `client.run` works](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/client.py#L780-L865). Internally, `client.run` calls [`asyncio.run`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/client.py#L860). Why is this important? Because you can not call `asyncio.run` from a current event loop. This is noted in the [Python documentation for asyncio.run()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-runner.html#asyncio.run). To fix your code, you must remove  everything from your `start` function to only call `asyncio.run` once.

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

# Note you did not include intents in your code block. This is a required
# parameter as of Discord.py 2.0.
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents=intents)
    
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready")
    
client.run('token')
```